# How to create a single polygon from GPS coordinates and find its area of that polygon

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, gps, gis, geojson

I need to create a polygon and draw it on the map from GPS coordinates. 
The GPS coordinates are taken from the android phone while the land leveler working the crop fields.
[image]
The results are not satisfactory.

```
from geojson import Polygon
import geojson

from area import area
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

long_coords = df['Longitude'].tolist()
lat_coords = df['Latitude'].tolist()

data = []
for i in range(0, len(long_coords)):

    data.append( tuple([long_coords[i],lat_coords[i]]) )

data.append(data[0])


print("Total GPS Coordinates: {}".format(len(data)))


obj = Polygon([data])  
print("Total Area : {} ".format(area(obj)))


f = open("data.geojson", "w")
f.write(str(obj))
f.close()
```

The GeoJson result is stored in [data.geojson:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfCIJ5QoN1M1B6hGMF-PtKHqgjc_Jlu8/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
Not getting the results expected, I want a single polygon with no holes in it.

The result that I expect,
[image]

The GPS Coordinates CSV File is : [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDWQFeDahqHIBCjXSflJcXQQyWjzaTzR/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I would try here is called Convex Hull.

I work mostly in SQL, but I found couple implementations in Python:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_convex_hull.html

You basically feed the algorithm all your points and it outputs the smallest convex polygon that encloses all of them.

Note that it is slightly different from your results, your polygon is concave. There are some heuristic algorithms for Concave Hull - but there is no unique way to describe the result you want, and different heuristics produce different results.

Comment: Thank you so much, Micheal. Your answer helps a lot. I found the big daddy Qhull is a Python package. Unfortunately, it doesn't have Concave Hull. I found some promising implementation in Node.js.  [Concaveman](https://github.com/mapbox/concaveman) also have a  [C++ port which has a Python wrapper](https://github.com/sadaszewski/concaveman-cpp) and it is extremely faster and promising results. Please include them in your answer.